# Windows 10 machine unresponsive to remote login after presumed and confirmed reboots

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-desktop-services, reboot

### Edit: May 5 2020 11:30 EDT (New York) time:

When I regained remote access, the software upgrade that I thought had caused the problem started (or restarted) and required a reboot. Luckily this happened while I was available, and I restarted successfully. So this is evidence that the server upgrade did not cause the problem.

Checking the event viewer, I see that the last entry on April 28 was at 9:19 PM. There is nothing in the events leading up to that which indicate there was a critical problem or an imminent restart. Next set of entries is on May 1 starting at 1:34 PM (when the floor manager powered on the server by pushing the button). There is a kernel general message followed by seven kernel boot messages, all at Information level. Then there is an Error-level message from the event log, at 1:35:22 PM:

> The previous system shutdown at 9:45:04 PM on ‎4/‎28/‎2020 was
>   unexpected.

And this at 1:35:12 PM:

> The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This
>   error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or
>   lost power unexpectedly.

So I no longer have any hypothesis with very much evidence to support it. Maybe a temporary power cut, but I have not heard about one from the IT staff, and even if it happened, the server should have rebooted.

[image: Event viewer with error message shortly after restart]

### Edit: May 1 2020 2:04 EDT (New York) time:

The server is currently accepting Remote Desktop logins after a person has rebooted the machine via the power button, but I am still hoping to understand what happened so that I can prevent it from becoming unresponsive in the future.

I've updated the timeline with the latest events, which were not what I expected.

In response to a helpful comment about the power plan, I inspected every aspect of it that I could see, including advanced options, and the only option related to turning off automatically was "Put the computer to sleep," which is set to "Never."

### Original post with updated timeline:

The Windows 10 Enterprise (v1803) machine that I need to access remotely during the covid-19 quarantine is not responding to Remote Desktop logins. This has happened multiple times, each time overnight and each time while I was anticipating a scheduled Windows security patch install with reboot, or after a person physically powered on the machine without logging in. From the evidence I have, it’s appearing that the machine powers down if it reboots and no one logs in for some amount of time. Is this a known behavior? Googling, I have not found any policy that has machines powering down on their own after no login. Is it possible to disable it? I would like the machine to stay powered on and responding to remote connections if it comes up and no one logs in, even for a long time.

The hard drive is BitLocker encrypted, but we have disabled the BitLocker boot prompt indefinitely via the PowerShell command

`Suspend-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -RebootCount 0`

Here’s the timeline that informs my hypothesis:

April 15 evening: Left my Remote Desktop connection anticipating an announced Windows security patch install and restart scheduled for an unknown future time.

April 16 morning: Machine not responding to Remote Desktop login.

April 19 evening: IT administrator on an emergency visit presses the power button, waits for the Windows login screen to appear, then leaves.

April 20 morning: Machine it not responding to Remote Desktop login.

April 22 evening: I make an emergency visit and see the machine is powered down. I power it up and log in, then lock the login and leave the facility.

April 23-28 Remote Desktop logins work fine.

April 29 evening: On a Remote Desktop connection, anticipating another announced Windows security patch install, I reboot the machine, log in again via Remote Desktop and leave it running for the evening.

April 30 morning: Machine not responding to Remote Desktop login.

May 1 early afternoon: Company floor manager inspected the front panel and reported the light in the power button is on constantly and not indicating sleep, but the hard drive light is not flashing. Pressing and quickly releasing the power button has no apparent effect. Pressing the power button for 10 seconds, the power button is showing a yellow light, then a white light, and then the machine powers down. Pressing it a third time, the machine powers on, shows the Dell POST screen and at length settles on a Windows login screen. I log in successfully via Remote Desktop.

Before the visit on May 1, I had anticipated that we would see an unlit power button, but it was lit.

Many thanks for any assistance!

Comment: All of that and no check for what power plan is configured?

Comment: I have very little knowledge of Windows, but isn't it so that you have to specify if a service can run without desktop?  And isn't RDP a service?  There was also some kind of memory limit to set (or increase) for services without desktop.

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks for that, I have updated the post to indicate what I found out about the power plan.

Comment: You don't write anything about the events from Windows event log. If a system shuts down or enters suspend it is all recorded there. Hence you should check this log.

Comment: @Robert Thanks, I updated the post with information from the event viewer.

Comment: @BuzzyHopewell Ok an unexpected shutdown. This can mean BSOD or a power outage (or somebody pressed the power button for >4sec). You can use [BlueScreenView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to check the kernel/memory dumps (if they are activated). The stack trace and the involved dlls and drivers can give you a hint what have caused the BSOD. If it wasn't a BSOD it can be a dying PSU or a defect cable.

Comment: @Robert Thanks again. I ran BlueScreenView and it showed zero blue screen events. So I think I am dealing with a power event.